# Cloud Messaging (GCM to FCM)

Tags: java, google-cloud-messaging

I am using the library com.google.android.gcm.server currently, i decided to change to fcm, as what i know gcm and fcm do not have much different on each other except the send_endpoint.

How can reuse the library which only need to change the gcm_send_endpoint to fcm_send_endpoint? Any recommendation of similar official library for fcm?

Your replied is greatly appreciated. Thank in advance

Comment: Which library are you using? The FCM endpoint is back compatible with GCM, so just changing the URL should work.

Comment: i using these com.google.android.gcm.server , the official gcm api, but i change the endpoint of this library ~ Or how can i change it ? is there any official FCM library for http server use ? Thank you

Comment: How old is the version you're using? The latest one in the GitHub repo seems to use the FCM endpoint.

Comment: I am using 1.0.0 verision :
Maven:

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.gcm/gcm-server -->

<dependency>

    <groupId>com.google.gcm</groupId>

    <artifactId>gcm-server</artifactId>

    <version>1.0.0</version>

</dependency>

Comment: Too old, I guess. Either build the library yourself, or subclass the `Sender` to use the FCM endpoint.

Comment: I know it is too old, but there is no newer version available yet ...

Comment: How can i  include the existing latest fcm github repo project (https://github.com/google/gcm) into my project ?

Comment: When i build the gcm latest project in jar, there is no class inside the jar, and i can't find any latest jar for it , anyone ?

Comment: There's an ant build file in _client-libraries/java/rest-client_. Run `ant` in that directory. It builds _gcm-server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar_ in the _dist_ directory.